# C# Winform title automatically centered? VS 2015 RC

Tags: c#, winforms

I was working on a project at work and bought it home to work on.  At work, I use Windows 7, at home Windows 8.1.

In both cases, I am using VS 2015 RC.

At home, all my forms have the title text (the 'Text' field of a form) centered.  I can't for the life of me work out why.

I've tried creating a totally new solution, and the same thing happens.

The only difference I can see is that I'm using Win 8.1 at home.

There isn't any property (that I can see) that will allow the setting of the text to 'centered', and even if there was, that's not what I want.

If anyone can shed some light on this, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: what u try to say me ?Iam totaly confussed..

Comment: @op what the comments above are trying to say is that your question has nothing to do with programming, and so it is off topic.

Comment: The question is:  Is the title centered because I'm running Windows 8, or have I done something programatically that I didn't realise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've answered your own question. Windows 8 centers titles, Windows 7 does not. This is a function of the OS, not your project.

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping someone could confirm that for me.